# Microsoft SQL: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerquery

I am new to SQL and trying to use Power Query to pull Great Plains data into Excel directly using a UDF that I found [here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/) to pass parameters from the workbook to the query.  Here is the UDF:

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=
if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
Value
```

and here is the SQL query:

```
Declare @accrualDate Date
set @accrualDate = dbo.fnGetParameter("Accrual Date")
Declare @lookback Date
set @lookback = dbo.fnGetParameter("Lookback for Automated Accruals")
Declare @lookbackBOP Date
set @lookbackBOP = dbo.fnGetParameter("Lookback for Manual Accruals - BOP")
Declare @lookbackEOP Date
set @lookbackEOP = dbo.fnGetParameter("Lookback for Manual Accruals - EOP")

SELECT
[Open Year], 
[History Year],
[Period ID], 
[TRX Date],
[Account Number], 
[Account Description], 
[Journal Entry],
[description],
[reference],
[Originating Posted Date],
Sum([Debit Amount]) AS [Debit Amount], 
Sum([Credit Amount]) AS [Credit Amount] ,

Segment1, 
Segment2, 
Segment3, 
Segment4, 
Segment5, 
Segment6, 
Segment7

FROM ['dbName'].[dbo].[AccountTransactions]
WHERE Segment2 BETWEEN 6000 AND 6999
and [description] = 'Purchases'
and [TRX Date] BETWEEN @lookback AND @accrualDate
GROUP BY [Open Year], [History Year], [Period ID], [TRX Date], [Account Number], [Account Description], [Journal Entry],[description],[reference], [Originating Posted Date], Segment1, Segment2, Segment3, Segment4, Segment5, Segment6, Segment7
```

I have run the UDF by itself, and have confirmed that it returns the expected values from my "Parameters" table.  However, when running the query I get the following error:

> DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Cannot find either column "dbo" or
>   the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnGetParameter", or the
>   name is ambiguous. Details:
>       DataSourceKind=SQL
>       DataSourcePath=dcb-gp15-sql.us.medsolutions.com;MED01
>       Message=Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnGetParameter", or
>   the name is ambiguous.
>       Number=4121
>       Class=16

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `dbo.fnGetParameter`? If it is a [table-valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) then you cannot use it as a scalar function

Comment: Is `fnGetParameter` an Excel function? It's not clear.

Comment: fnGetParameter is the name of the UDF that I created using Power Query > From Other Sources > Blank Query > Advanced Editor.  Sorry, I should have been more clear about that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The custom "M" function `fnGetParameter` is only defined when running mashups in Power Query, and isn't sent to the server.

If you specify a native SQL query from Power Query, that's literally what we send to the server. Power Query doesn't give you a way to define custom UDF on the server.

---

Instead you could import the `AccountTransactions` table into Power Query, and use "M" transformations to transform the table. I'd recommend using the UI to generate the row filters and summation aggregations, and then customize the "M" to use your customer filter.

e.g. one of your steps would be something like:

```
FilteredRows3 = Table.SelectRows(
    FilteredRows2,
    each
        fnGetParameter("Lookback for Automated Accruals") < [TRX Date] 
      and 
        [TRX Date] < fnGetParameter("Accrual Date")
)
```